# onValueSelected callback received when clicking outside of circles in LineChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I have a `LineChart` created using MPAndroidChart. I have set an `OnChartValueSelectedListener` for this chart and till now everything works good. Except the `onValueSelected` function is getting called if I click anywhere on chart. It should only get called upon clicking on circles (value points) inside the chart.

I have tried so many options for this, but no luck.

Can anyone explain to me how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got it solved:

The working of `setOnChartValueSelectedListener` is based on highlighting. When you click on chart, by default the closest point (`Entry`) gets highlighted. So anywhere you click on chart the`onValueSelected` will be called for nearest point (`Entry`).

So to prevent this, we need to set **setMaxHighlightDistance** property of chart.

Following line did work for me:

```
mChart.setMaxHighlightDistance(20);
```